# Recursion in python web crawler

Tags: python

I am attempting to make a little web crawler in python.  What seems to be tripping me up right now is the recursive part and depth of this problem.  Given a url and a maxDepth of how many sites from there I want to link to I then add the url to the set of searched sites, and download all the text and links from the site.  For all the links that the url has in it, I want to search each link and get it's words and links.  What the problem is, is that when I go to recursively call the next url, the depth is already at maxDepth and it stops after going to only 1 more page.  Hopefully I explained it decently, basically the question I am asking is how do I do all the recursive calls and then set self._depth += 1?

```
def crawl(self,url,maxDepth):        

    self._listOfCrawled.add(url)

    text = crawler_util.textFromURL(url).split()

    for each in text:
        self._index[each] = url

    links = crawler_util.linksFromURL(url)

    if self._depth < maxDepth:
        self._depth = self._depth + 1
        for i in links:
            if i not in self._listOfCrawled:
                self.crawl(i,maxDepth)
```

Comment: You should check out [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) - It's all open source, so you can look at the design for some ideas..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you increase `self.depth` each time you call the function, and since it is a variable of the instance, it *stays* increased in the following calls. Let's say `maxDepth` is 3 and you have a URL `A` that links to pages `B`, and `C`, and `B` links to `D`, and `C` has a link to `E`. Your call hierarchy then looks like this (assuming that `self._depth` is 0 at the beginning):

```
crawl(self, A, 3)          # self._depth set to 1, following links to B and C
    crawl(self, B, 3)      # self._depth set to 2, following link to D
        crawl(self, D, 3)  # self._depth set to 3, no links to follow
    crawl(self, C, 3)      # self._depth >= maxDepth, skipping link to E
```

In other words, instead of the `depth` of the current call, you track the *accumulated* number of calls to `crawl`.

Instead, try something like this:

```
def crawl(self,url,depthToGo):
    # call this method with depthToGo set to maxDepth
    self._listOfCrawled.add(url)
    text = crawler_util.textFromURL(url).split()
    for each in text:
        # if word not in index, create a new set, then add URL to set
        if each not in self._index:
            self._index[each] = set([])
        self._index[each].add(url)
    links = crawler_util.linksFromURL(url)
    # check if we can go deeper
    if depthToGo > 0:
        for i in links:
            if i not in self._listOfCrawled:
                # decrease depthToGo for next level of recursion
                self.crawl(i, depthToGo - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me! I actually have another problem...not sure if you can help but.. I have realized that when I assign the url to the value of each text, and then go to another url with the same word, the original url gets replaced by the last one.  Is there a way to make the value a list of the urls?

Comment: I fixed that in my answer, but using a set instead of a list. You might also consider using a set for the URLs already crawled, since lookups in sets are much faster.